# NameError: name 'tokenize' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, tokenize

To to Sentiment Analysis Classification : We trained various machine learning models and deep neural networks to classify the sentiment of review text into 3 main categories (Positive, Neutral, Negative).

```
# TfidfVectorizer transform train and test
    con_vec = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english',tokenizer=tokenize,max_features=20000,ngram_range=(1,2))
    X_train_tfidf = con_vec.fit_transform(X_train)
    # with open("tfidf_vectorizer.pkl", 'wb') as handle:
    #                     pickle.dump(con_vec, handle)
    y_train_tfidf = y_train
    X_test_tfidf = con_vec.transform(X_test)
    y_test_tfidf = y_test

**ERROR CODE :** 
    **Pandas Version is pandas 1.1.4**
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

      1 from nltk import word_tokenize # Generate table of words with their counts
      2 from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize # TfidfVectorizer transform train and test
----> 3 con_vec = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english',tokenizer=tokenize,max_features=20000,ngram_range=(1,2))
      4 X_train_tfidf = con_vec.fit_transform(X_train)
    
  
    **NameError: name 'tokenize' is not defined**

Any solution how to remove this error?
Also tried from **nltk import word_tokenize** but still same error 
    
      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmoSp.png
```

Comment: There is no defintion of `tokenize` in your code, which you used in `TfidfVectorizer`.

Comment: Add your imports to the code snippet

Comment: It means exactly what it sounds like. Do you have a question?

Answer (score 1):

Try importing it:

```
from nltk.tokenize import tokenize
```

Answer (score 0):

I am receiving the below message:

```
      1 import nltk
----> 2 from nltk.tokenize import tokenize
      3 import re

ImportError: cannot import name 'tokenize' from 'nltk.tokenize' (/Users/user/miniforge3/envs/base_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/__init__.py)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)